# ZIP files comparison

Tags: zip, compression

I am trying to verify that two ZIP files have the same content.  I assumed that if I unzip and immediately rezip a group of files (using the same zip function) the zip files should be identical.  They appear not to be identical.  There sha256sums are different and they appear to be different.  I unzipped both of these new zip files and there contents are identical.
  Why would the zip files not be the same for two identical set of files/directories?

Answer (score 1):

As you have discovered, that is an entirely incorrect assumption.  You should compare the uncompressed contents if you want to know if the contents are the same.  You could also just look at the entry names, lengths, and CRCs to get a high probability verification, without having to decompress.

The zip file can be different for many reasons.  The order of the files in the zip file do not need to be the same.  The modification dates of the files are stored in the zip file, so if they are not restored they will be different.  A different compression level or different compression software (even just a different version of the same software) could be used, resulting in different output.  Different compression methods could have been chosen.  Different file metadata (permissions, etc.) or other extra fields could be included in one zip file, but not the other, e.g. Unix permissions.  Different variants of the zip format might be used, e.g. Zip64.  The list goes on.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  It appears that there are many reasons why the Zip file might and/or would be different.  Your comment that I should do my compares on the <uncompressed> content seems to sum up this issue.  Can one rely on the Extracted Contents being the same, even as the compressed files seem to vary?  Maybe fingerprinting of the uncompressed content using sha256sum OR md5sum might be a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

The zip format supports different compression levels and might store file attributes (like file timestamp), so this has to be expected.